# Create Lazy Sequency by Concatenating Collections

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

Create a lazy sequence by concatenating collections.

Consider the following function:

```
(defn req []
  (Thread/sleep 1000)
  (repeat 4 (rand-int 10)))
```

The sleep is added since the function will finally be a http request, thus it should emulate a delay.

Sample outputs:

```
(req)
;; (8 8 8 8)

(req)
;; (4 4 4 4)
```

I'm thinking of a function now, that creates a lazy sequence build by the concatenation of subsequent `req` results.

```
(take 10 (f req))
;; (3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 9 9)
```

Here is one implementation:

```
(defn f [g]
  (lazy-seq (concat (g) (f g))))
```

Is this the way to go? I'm somehow guessing that there might be already an abstraction for this available.. I tried `lazy-cat`, but this macro seems to work only for a fixed number of given sequences.

---

It turns out that this is a working abstraction:

```
(take 10 (apply concat (repeatedly req)))
```

However it looks like chunking of lazy sequences causes `req` to be called more often than needed here, which would not be acceptable if it's an http request.

Comment: Another variation: (take 10 (map (fn [_] (req)) (range)))

Comment: This is not working. It returns a list of lists instead of a list. It's omitting the concat part of it.

Comment: Sorry--small correction: (take 10 (mapcat (fn [_] (req)) (range)))

Comment: @DarrylG this also leads to redundant realization of elements of lazy sequence

Comment: @OlegTheCat: example output this provides is: (5 5 5 5 9 9 9 9 3 3)  Isn't this the same as the problem description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "unneeded" realizations of elements of lazy sequence is happening because `apply` [needs to know](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/4ff462372c29ff2bc22b4d39962ad526f7e2c73d/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RestFn.java#L130) the number of arguments that passed function is applied to.

Having a quick look at Clojure core lib, it seems, that it doesn't provide a function that concatenates a sequence of sequences and, at the same time, handles laziness in a way you want (doesn't redundantly realize the elements of passed lazy sequence), so, you'll need to implement it yourself.

Here's possible solution:

```
(defn apply-concat [xs]
  (lazy-seq
   (when-let [s (seq xs)]
     (concat (first s) (apply-concat (rest s))))))
```

And then:

```
user> (defn req []
        (println "--> making request")
        [1 2 3 4])
#'user/req
user> (dorun (take 4 (apply-concat (repeatedly req))))
--> making request
nil
user> (dorun (take 5 (apply-concat (repeatedly req))))
--> making request
--> making request
nil
user> (dorun (take 8 (apply-concat (repeatedly req))))
--> making request
--> making request
nil
user> (dorun (take 9 (apply-concat (repeatedly req))))
--> making request
--> making request
--> making request
nil
```

<del>The only concern with this approach is danger of blowing the stack, since `apply-concat` is potentially infinitely recursive.</del>

Update:

To be precise `apply` realizes `(arity of passed function + 1)` elements of passed lazy sequence:

```
user> (dorun (take 1 (apply (fn [& xs] xs) (repeatedly req))))
--> making request
--> making request
nil
user> (dorun (take 1 (apply (fn [x & xs] xs) (repeatedly req))))
--> making request
--> making request
--> making request
nil
user> (dorun (take 1 (apply (fn [x y & xs] xs) (repeatedly req))))
--> making request
--> making request
--> making request
--> making request
nil
```

Comment: There are no stack concerns here. The stack-trampolining effect of lazy seqs takes care of all the problems. You can see for yourself with, eg, `(last (apply-concat (repeat 1e6 [1])))`.

Comment: @OlegTheCat I'm still struggling with the question, if it's due to apply that the first 4 items are evaluated. To me it looks like `(apply concat (repeatedly req))` does take the first fn definition of apply (apply ([f args] ..)). Would you agree with that?

Comment: So I have doubts that apply causes this. Look at this: `(take 1 (apply (fn [& xs] xs) (repeatedly req)))`  - it evaluates req only 2 times.

Comment: @AntonHarald The number of evaluated elements depends on arity function passed to apply (as I mentioned in my answer this is due to apply realizes as many elements as passed function accepts plus one). So `(take 1 (apply (fn [& xs] xs) (repeatedly req)))` realized `req` two times, `(take 1 (apply (fn [x & xs] (cons x xs)) (repeatedly req)))` - three times, `(take 1 (apply (fn [x y & xs] (cons x (cons y xs))) (repeatedly req)))` - four times, and so on.

Comment: Alright, I see now. So it's concats [x y & zs] plus one that causes the 4 initial evals. Too bad actually, I'd say without this, there would be quite some situations more, where the power of lazy sequences could be used.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
(take 14 
  (mapcat identity (repeatedly req)))
```

explanation:

```
(defn req [] 
  (print ".") 
  (repeat 4 (rand-int 10)))

(def x 
  (take 80 (mapcat identity (repeatedly req))))
; prints .... = 4x ; this is probably some repl eagerness

; to take 80 items, 20 realizatons (of 4 items) are requrend 
(def y 
  (doall
    (take 80 (mapcat identity (repeatedly req))))) 
 ; prints ..................... = 21x
```

EDIT: about those 4 early realizations:

I think  this is due `apply`, which us used by `mapcat`.
It realizes up to 4 args `[^clojure.lang.IFn f a b c d & args]` given multiple ones.

Comment: as I said, its either a repl-eagerness or a clojure seq chunking - (clojure used to realize by 1 and this behaviour got changed to realize the next 32 items in clojure.1.1 I think), I'm investigating the exact cause right now.

Comment: @OlegTheCat, I'm pretty sure this is due `apply`, which us used by `mapcat`. It realizes up to 4 args `[^clojure.lang.IFn f a b c d & args]` given multiple ones - but I might be wrong. So yeah `take 0-16` will always at least realize 4 chunks up front, whereas `take 17` will realize 4 times up front but only after 16 items again